# Google Cloud Dataflow Job - Refusing to split

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

What are the most common reasons for Dataflow job to fail with the following message:

```
The work item was attempted on these workers: wn-vlg-to-1vro-1606304136-11250335-91et-harness-n08k Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.
```

I've also observed multiple "Refusing to split..." prints in the worker logs:

```
Refusing to split GroupedShuffleReader <dataflow_worker.shuffle.GroupedShuffleReader object at 0x7f6a231c4a90> at BZt9HwAB
```

job_id="2020-11-25_04_58_21-4901626503823103758"

Comment: Is it a batch or streaming pipeline? For a batch pipeline, `The worker lost contact with the service` is logged after the work item fails 4 times. It's usually some other error causing the pipeline to fail. You might want to check the worker log for other errors. Is `Refusing to split GroupedShuffleReader` an info level log or error? Workers might log something at info level when rebalancing the work, but it does not necessarily mean there is an error. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510996/refusing-to-split-groupedshufflerangetracker-proposed-split-position-is-out-of-r

Comment: @大ドア東, this is a batch pipeline. Refusing to split is an info level log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason for a Dataflow job to fail with “Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service” is you running out of memory.

You can identify memory issues within the Stackdriver Logs using an advanced filter like [1] (take a look at [2] too).

Possible solutions are to set higher memory worker machines types, or decrease the parallelism of processing, using the pipeline option `--numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads` (or `--number_of_worker_harness_threads` for Python).

[1]

```
resource.type="dataflow_step"
resource.labels.job_id="YOUR_JOB_ID"
severity>=WARNING
("thrashing=true" OR "OutOfMemoryError" OR "Out of memory" OR "Shutting down JVM")
```

[2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#getting-started

Comment: Thanks, setting higher memory worker machine type has seemed to fix this.